# How to use charts in streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I write an app that generates some df. I am trying to add a line graph so that the DataFrame can be better visualised. But I keep getting the same error when I want to determine the columns for the x and y-axis.
This is my code for the line chart:

```
st.line_chart(raport4,x="rasa",y=[["blup_zwh","zwh2","zwh3","zwh4","zwh5","zwh6"]])
```

And this is my DF and the  Error:
[image]

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please some reproducible data? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: What version of Streamlit are you using? Passing x= to st.line_chart wasn't supported until relatively recently so I would guess that you're using an older version -- upgrade to the most recent version and that would resolve the issue

Comment: @CarolineFrasca Thanks you were right I just need to upgrade my streamlit version.